# Cross-referencing between different files 

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

I want to cross-reference between different `.tex` files, just because I want to put every chapters separately.

Let's say in file `chapterI.tex` I have `\label{a}` and I want to access this in file `chapterII.tex` using something like `\ref{a}`. How to do this exactly in LaTeX, moreover if `LEd` have an easy feature to cover this, it will be better (I have put those both files in the same project).

I found another question with similar title, but I just didn't really understand. It's here: [Cross-reference between LaTeX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/cross-reference-between-latex-files).

Comment: You can certainly make a cross-reference across files like you want. `\label{a}` in one file, and `\ref{a}` in another. What's not working? Is there a minimal working example that shows the problem?

Comment: @Mike: and how to "compile" it into pdf or dvi exactly? I tried to do that, and it's still `??` after several tries.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify it: Are the chapters all part of one document or are they all separated documents? In the first case it should work out of the box like @Mike said. The second case is described in my answer.

Comment: @zfm: Since your accepted answer has nothing to do with LEd, perhaps you might change your title to "Cross reference between files in LaTeX" so that the question has broader appeal.

Comment: @mforbes: will do it!

Comment: @zfm I think "Cross-referencing between different documents" would be even more appropriate as a title.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You can use the [`xr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr) package to reference to other LaTeX documents.

So, in `chapterII.tex`, you say:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{chapterI}
```

And then can use `\ref{a}` like normal.
You can also add a prefix:

```
\externaldocument[I-]{chapterI}
```

Then, you can reference it as `\ref{I-a}` which is useful if you have identical label names in different chapters.

Note that the normal `xr` doesn't add hyperlinks. It only adds the label text. The [`zref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) package can be used for this. It provides the `zref-xr` subpackage which gives you the same functionality and should work fine with [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (after all both packages are from the same author).
You only need to replace `\externaldocument` with `\zexternaldocument` and `\ref` with `\zref`.

Note that the `xr` package reads the `aux` file, e.g. in this case, it checks `chapterI.aux` for references.

Comment: @Martin: It might be useful to mention that you need to replace `\usepackage{xr}` with \usepackage{zref-xr}`.  (I was not sure what a "subpackage" was when I first read your answer.)

Comment: @Martin: I am stumped: how do you get `hyperref` to work with `zref-xr`?  Using `\zref` and `\zlabel` (with `\usepackage{zref-user}`) generates the labels properly, but I cannot get hyper refs working.  Could you please post a MWE or should I ask a related question emphasizing the `hyperref` aspect?

Comment: @mforbes: Did you solve this? I posted it as a new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127495/2210) some days ago.

Comment: @CarstenThiel Nope.

Comment: But what I wanna cross-ref a figure in B.tex from A.tex, which is an unrunnable snippet? I have a structure file that has all the preambles. Both A and B are simply two snippets that cannot use any  packages. How may I do it in this case?

Comment: One extra thing: if you use hyperref in one document you must use it in the other document otherwise the reference text will be something like `1[section name]section.1` instead of just `1` (see http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6531).

Comment: Very helpful. But why oh why isn't this automatic for documents included via `\input` or `\include`?...

Comment: @beldaz: I don't know what you mean. Files included via `\input` and `\include` will be crossreferenced like normal. Are you talking about including a complete other document this way?

Comment: @Martin: cross referencing didn't seem to work for input files without declaring them as external documents with xr. Could be I'm wrong, so will check later.

Comment: @beldaz: No, that is not the case. It is very normal to have your chapters in `\include` files and then internal cross referencing is working like a charm. You just have to compile twice of course, or maybe more often in some cases (TOC page count changed since last run, etc.)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I have documents that `\input` content (including whole `\begin{document} ... \end{ducoment}` for which I have to explicitly declare `\externaldocument` to get references to work. Perhaps it works for you when you're dealing with smaller parts of a document, but I think my case is different.

Comment: I cannot get working example with hyperref and zref-xr although with xr-hyper it works. My file B: 
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
%\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{A}
\begin{document}
\section{Shafranov}\label{Shafranov}
Shafranov
\newpage
\section{Kotelnikov}\label{Kotelnikov}
Kotelnikov
\newpage
\section{Refs}
\hyperref[Dittmar]{hyperref to Dittmar}
\hyperref[Langmuir]{hyperref to Langmuir}
\hyperref[Shafranov]{hyperref to Shafranov}
\hyperref[Kotelnikov]{hyperref to Kotelnikov}
\end{document}
Can someome modify it pf zref?

Comment: `zref-xr` does not create hyperlinks. `hyperref` module is not ninished in `zref`.

Comment: One gotcha here: when in doubt, eliminate spaces in your filenames.

Comment: @dshepherd: thanks so much, your comment save me a lot of pain.

Comment: It seems that including `.tex` extension to the file path in `\externaldocument{...}` ruins the whole thing, just a warning.

Comment: In my case, I cannot get the `zref-xr` working. `xr` however, works out of the box ... provided that `*.synctex.gz` file of the external document is present. If not, some kind of an infinite loop occurs.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: It is not clear whether with the `zref-xt` package, the cross-references and labels must all be given with the `z` prefix (e.g. `\zref` and `\zlabel`) also in the external document, or not. Could you clarify this? Also, does it matters in what order are the `zref-xr` and `hyperref` packages loaded? Usually, `hyperref` is preferred to be loaded last ...

Comment: Is it possible to get the pageref? Like for example, in Document 2, I want to reference the label, and also the page that label appears in Document 1?

Comment: this is useful and working. We can refer equations from external document but equation numbers in new document clash with old so for this we can use set the starting line number using:
\setcounter{equation}{16}

Comment: @SibbsGambling it sounds like you normally compile the whole document (with your structure file), but need to compile a version with only `A.tex` that cross references to `B.tex` without additional packages. I needed to do something similar for a manuscript submission that wanted a `main.tex` and a `supplementary.pdf`. You can manually steal the `\newlabel` commands from the combined `aux` file.

Comment: This works well for me, thanks! I must emphasize that I was compiling in my local machine. However, the package cannot read the `aux` file when you use an online TeX editor like Overleaf. That being said, make sure you compile locally and then upload the `aux` file to the overleaf repository.

Comment: For this to work should we compile `chapterI.tex` file first like: `pdflatex chapterI.tex` ?

Comment: @alper: Yes, correct.

Answer (score 26):

As explained earlier `xr` or `xr-hyper` do the trick. They need however the corresponding `.aux` file of the included file. Online LaTeX editors like overleaf do not present these files. A solution is given [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf):

in your preamble after including the 'xr' package define some helper functions

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
    \externaldocument{#1}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
```

Then include your external document with `\myexternaldocument{...}` (note the *my*)

Then add a file called `latexmkrc` with the following content:

```
add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'aux', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );

sub makeexternaldocument {
    if (!($root_filename eq $_[0]))
    {
        system( "latexmk -cd -pdf \"$_[0]\"" );
    }
}
```

Now the required `.aux` file will be preserved, and you are good to go.

Comment: +1 for including instructions for Overleaf

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck with Overleaf and this solved it for me!

Comment: Can this solution applied for the non-Online LaTeX editors using `pdflatex`? or should I require to compile subfiles first in order to create their `.aux` files?

Answer (score 16):

**Beamer and xr:** If you want to use the `xr` package to pull external references into a Beamer document, you need to be sure that the source of the references has been typeset using the `hyperref` package. This is because Beamer uses hyperref by default and the format of the references in the .aux file is different for `hyperref`. If the references are coming from another Beamer document, there is no need to do anything. If they are coming from a basic LaTeX document you may need to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` and typeset the source document again. As far as I can tell, there is no downside to *always* using `hyperref`.

Answer (score 14):

This [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-extref.html) from the UK TUG suggests to use `xr-hyper` if using `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[V1-]{volume1}    % Not volume1.tex
...
... (see Volume~I, Section~\ref{V1-sIntroduction}) ...
```

The FAQ cites `zref-xr` as a superset.

Dear users of `zref`: please edit this answer to list some benefits of `zref`.

Comment: FAQ links seems dead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fully functioning minimal LaTeX template at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/sashwattanay/Thesis-Report-LaTeX-Template) to do just that. Separate chapters stay in separate source files with cross-referencing enabled. Also, there is no problem if the label names in two different source files clash. See the readme for the repo to see how all this works.

Answer (score -1):

`subfiles` also a solution for this, usage is:

```
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{file.tex}
```

Comment: Please make your answer a complete one (including a compilable example). Remember: The main aim is not including a file, but referencing.

Comment: The `subfiles` package has no influence at all on cross-referencing.

Comment: what if it references from multiple subfiles?

Answer (score -1):

That works well for me:

```
\chapter{tobereferenced} \label{tobereferenced}

bla bla bla \ref{tobereferenced}.
```

Credits: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Cross%20referencing%20sections,%20equations%20and%20floats

Answer (score -1):

To expand on @MadyYuvi's answer, if you use the `subfiles` package you can just put your references in as you would in a single document, and they will compile and work just fine. This worked wonders for me.