# How can I automatically copy a LyX-generated .aux file to the working directory for cross referencing?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lyx, auxiliary-files, xr

This is a follow up to: [Using the xr package in LyX (for cross-referencing an external LyX document)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39772/using-the-xr-package-in-lyx-for-cross-referencing-an-external-lyx-document)

I have two LyX documents, called `draft.lyx` and `supplement.lyx`. I need to compile them into separate documents and be able to cross reference from the supplement to the draft. I am attempting to use xr per the instruction linked to above.

Normally, I use a little python script to call LyX sequentially to compile each file from the command line. However, it seems that the temp folder only persists while LyX is running, so the necessary .aux file is deleted before it can be referenced. Is there a way to automatically copy the .aux file or to force the temp directory to persist?

Comment: I don't have time to look into this, but you might find some useful information in Help > Customization. In particular, read the section on "copiers" and perhaps the flag "needaux" (for "converters").

Comment: Thanks @scottkosty. I took a look but the documentation seems to be specific to Linux/Unix. Do you know if there is documentation for windows?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could try sending an email to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org

Comment: This cross-referencing problem might be solved without copying .aux files and by using the GUI: All text can be put into one document using "branches". A detailed description can be found in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116911/24449) of the question "Lyx cross-referencing between branches".

Comment: I have the exact same question as the OP. Is there a solution that does not make use of branches?

Comment: A sub-optimal solution is to export both documents to Latex and then compiling them (so skipping Lyx in the compilation), I haven't found any other solution so far