# Carrying counters over to another file

Tags: counters

I have two files, say `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`. `file1.tex` is the first of a series of files, and it begins with counters (say chapter 1 for instance, although my counters are not used for chapters). Then at the end of `file1`, the counter for chapters is at say 7 ; I want to carry the value of the counter to `file2.tex` so that I can use a counter which will have the value 7 in `file2.tex`. In this way I could possibly carry on the counter in `file2.tex` to a counter in some `file3.tex` and so on.

I assume I would need to compile `file1.tex` first, and then `file2.tex`, and then `file3.tex`... of course.

Is that possible? And if so, how? I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: You can create a main file and `\include` or `\input` the files depending on your needs.  The main file will keep track of the counter.  Here is a thread on when to use either input or include: [Include vs Input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: @dustin : I'm not exactly sure if this will work ; I don't want to put in file2 some *code* sitting inside file1... I want to put in file2 the *value of some counter*. I'm going to read up on \input, but I don't see how that would work... \input and \include seem to put one file into another or something, which I don't want.

Comment: @dustin : It is not a book. I write many papers, and inside a paper, I want to refer to a theorem in another paper. Both may get modified over time, so I want something that can survive modifications. Usually it's notes or something. Anyway, I don't think \input or \include answers my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit though, didn't know how to do that.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) is what you are looking for I believe now that I know your intentions better.

Comment: @dustin : Are the values of my counters stored in the .aux file at the end of compilation? Because if it could store the counters values and I could read them up with a \value or \the-countername- command it would be great.

Comment: Did you see the link in my previous comment?  Martin Scharrer address accessing references in multiple documents that aren't part of one main file by using the package `xr`.  So if you label your theorem in `file1`, you can `\ref{thoerem}` in `file2.tex`.

Comment: @dustin : Yes, of course I did. I tried to work it out, and it seems to work with labels but not with counters. Is that possible? I am using counters via \newcounter, not \label. If I could assign a counter value to a label that would work too but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @dustin : We're almost there. I can use xr to cross-reference labels, and it does exactly what I want it to do. The only problem is that the number I'm trying to transfer from a file to another is not from a \label and outputtable with a \ref ; it is a counter and is outputtable with a \value or something.

Comment: So either I learn out to put a counter value into a label, or this package has some way of transferring counter values as well as labels.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: That's possible via [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) to retrieve labels from other documents and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to assign references (of labels) to counters (as reference, see [Cross-referencing between different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5764)):

#### `file1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storecounter}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\the\value{#1}}% Store current counter value in \@currentlabel
  \label{#2}% Store label
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{mycntr}
\begin{document}
Some text
\setcounter{mycntr}{12}\storecounter{mycntr}{first}
\setcounter{mycntr}{99}\storecounter{mycntr}{second}
\end{document}
```

This creates `file1.aux` which has the crucial bit of information regarding the label(s) and its associated value:

```
\newlabel{first}{{12}{1}}
\newlabel{second}{{99}{1}}
```

#### `file2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount,xr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{refcount,xr}
\newcommand*{\getcounter}[2]{%
  \setcounterref{#1}{#2}% Retrieve label value and store it in a counter
}
\externaldocument[file1:]{file1}
\newcounter{mycntr}
\begin{document}
Counter: \getcounter{mycntr}{file1:first}\themycntr \par
Counter: \getcounter{mycntr}{file1:second}\themycntr
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking at refcount to better understand your answer. Thanks for taking the time, I'll come back to you in a few minutes!

Comment: Why do you need
    `\section{A section}\label{---->file1<----:sec}`
this part in file1??

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: You don't *need* `file1` in the reference. I just wanted to make it clear from the example that the reference is coming from `file1.tex`. However, [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) also provides the means to supply a prefix for labels, as mentioned in [Cross-referencing between different files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5764), via `\externaldocument[file1]{<file>}`.

Comment: The command \setcounterref does the opposite of what I want ; since label values can go across files with the package xr, I wanted to assign a counter value to a label so that the counter value goes across the file. Your example shows how to carry a label value across files, that I can do. This is where I am stuck. I have a counter in file1 and I want its value to be carried over to file2. Do you understand my problem better?

Comment: In respond to your last comment ; yes, good.

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something wrong here. Am I being out of line by trying to carry that counter value across files?

Comment: Something like this, but I don't quite understand how to work it out : http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2006-July/006599.html

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: As I understand it, the principle is the same. I've updated my answer to use physical counters, but it's still using the same packages to extract numbers from references; it just seem like I'm transferring counters. If this does not answer your question, please include a document structure in your original post that explains the situation better...

Comment: So your home-made \storecounter command is the one that turns my counter values into labels? It looks quite complicated to setup... am I wrong thinking this is a TeX-made command, and not a LaTeX one? I can only do LaTeX so it looks like chinese to me, but it seems to work exactly the way I want it.

Comment: Actually I like this solution because I use counters to number my environments but it is nice to use \label and \ref to refer to my environments. Great answer!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: No, this is a LaTeX approach. If you search for the definition of `\refstepcounter` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) you'll "see" how it stores the current counter value in `\@currentlabel`, which is then written to the `.aux` when you issue `\label` (defined just above `\refstepcounter`). So I'm just using an alternative tool to do the same thing you're after.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I didn't know that. I know now what \makeatletter does but seeing that @ character at first made me think it was TeX because I never do that in LaTeX.

Comment: Using `\csname the#1\endcsname` is wrong. It should be `\the\value{#1}`. If the counter's representation is not in arabic numbers, you'll get into big troubles with `\setcounterref`.

Comment: @egreg: Exactly... older days; learned since then... thanks.