# How to suppress output when carrying over counters?

Tags: output

I've got a study book split into multiple individual books. To continue chapter and part numbers across volumes, I've used the solution by Werner provided here: [Carrying counters over to another file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129312/carrying-counters-over-to-another-file)

It's excellent!
One problem: the command to store counters generates output in the document. The command works for my situation, but it produces extra output upon saving the counters. My question is: how can I get rid of the extra output?

MWE (which gives a "Missing number, treated as zero" error but does produce a PDF if you power through by pressing enter):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn,openany]{book}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% load chapter/part counters from previous workbooks 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129312/carrying-counters-over-to-another-file
% ===========================================================================
\usepackage{refcount,xr}
\externaldocument{book1}
\externaldocument{book3}
% ---------------------------

% command for storing part/chapter counters
% ---------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storecounter}[2]{%
  % updated as per egreg's comment
  \edef\@currentlabel{\the\value{#1}}% Store current counter value in \@currentlabel
  \label{#2}% Store label
}
\makeatother

% command to get value of counters
% ---------------------------
\newcommand*{\getcounter}[2]{%
  \setcounterref{#1}{#2}% Retrieve label value and store it in a counter
}

% have a counter for chapters and for parts from volume 1
% ---------------------------
\newcounter{bookonecounter}
\getcounter{bookonecounter}{parts}
\setcounter{part}{\thebookonecounter}

\begin{document}

\part{A part}
\part{Another part}

% ===========================================================================
% Save chapter/part counters for use in further volumes
% XXX: this currently outputs "value in X"
% ---------------------------
\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\thechapter}\storecounter{bookonecounter}{chapters}
\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\thepart}\storecounter{bookonecounter}{parts}
% ===========================================================================

\end{document}
```

Using this example (volume 2) when you have volume 1 as "book1.tex" will correctly continue the part number. E.g., for a book1.aux that contains

```
\newlabel{chapters}{{4}{154}}
\newlabel{parts}{{2}{154}}
```

it compiles (with the complaint as noted above) into a pdf which continues the count. However, it adds a page to the end of the PDF which contains `IV`:
[image: output of MWE: extra page with "IV"]

Commenting out the two `setcounter/storecounter` lines removes this from the pdf.

**edit:** egreg's proposal is definitely an improvement. The screenshot is the result of using his definition. Unfortunately, there's still an extra, unwanted page with some text on it on account of the `\setcounter..\storecounter` lines.

Any ideas on how to prevent the lines with `\setcounter{}..\storecounter` to produce an extra page?

Comment: I'm afraid your code doesn't compile on my system (MacTeX2016), possibly because I don't have access to `book1.tex` and `book3.tex`. Could you give a hint at what crucial commands might be in `book1.tex`?

Comment: `\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\theparts}` won't work if `\thepart` is defined to use `\Roman`, i.e. it will use I, II, III, not 1, 2, 3.... the same problem arises with `\getcounter{bookonecounter}{parts}` then!

Comment: Simple: change `\edef\@currentlabel{\csname the#1\endcsname}` into `\edef\@currentlabel{\the\value{#1}}`

Comment: Now Werner has fixed his answer. I think that we can close this.

Comment: @mico: sorry, it also gives a compilation bug for me, which I can just ignore. Should've mentioned that.
relevant part of book1.aux:
`\newlabel{chapters}{{4}{154}}
\newlabel{parts}{{2}{154}}`

Comment: @egreg: thanks! I've now got it working - it's indeed what you and christian hupfer pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here: `\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\thepart}` won't work if `\thepart` will use `\Roman{...}` as counter output formatting, i.e. `I`, `II`, `III` etc. -- this can't be understood by `\setcounter` as valid input for counter values.

So never use `\setcounter{foo}{\thefoobar}` in almost any case!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn,openany]{book}

\begin{filecontents}{book1.tex}
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\begin{document}
\part{First part}\label{parts}

\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}


% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% load chapter/part counters from previous workbooks 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129312/carrying-counters-over-to-another-file
% ===========================================================================
\usepackage{refcount,xr}
\externaldocument{book1}
\externaldocument{book3}
% ---------------------------

% command for storing part/chapter counters
% ---------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storecounter}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\csname the#1\endcsname}% Store current counter value in \@currentlabel
  \label{#2}% Store label
}
\makeatother

% command to get value of counters
% ---------------------------
\newcommand*{\getcounter}[2]{%
  \setcounterref{#1}{#2}% Retrieve label value and store it in a counter
}

% have a counter for chapters and for parts from volume 1
% ---------------------------
\newcounter{bookonecounter}
\getcounter{bookonecounter}{parts}
\setcounter{part}{\value{bookonecounter}}

\begin{document}

\part{A part}
\part{Another part}

% ===========================================================================
% Save chapter/part counters for use in further volumes
% XXX: this currently outputs "value in X"
% ---------------------------
\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\value{chapter}}
\storecounter{bookonecounter}{chapters}
\setcounter{bookonecounter}{\value{part}}
\storecounter{bookonecounter}{parts}
% ===========================================================================

\end{document}
```