# Cross-reference between two tex files WITHOUT preamble?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a "structure" file `paper.tex` that inputs two section `.tex` files, `A.tex` and `B.tex`.

Both `A.tex` and `B.tex` do not have any preambles. i.e. they are simply two snippets. All the preambles are in `paper.tex`.

I now wish to cross-refer a figure in `A.tex` from `B.tex`. How may I do this?

[This answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) suggests using

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{chapterI}
```

But I think it won't work in my case, as the preambles are not allowed in `A.tex` and `B.tex`.

Comment: If they are both included into the main file, there is no problem. Near all is as if all three be in a common file. No packages are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are both included into the main file, there is no problem. Near all is as if all three be in a common file. No packages are needed. (Said Przemysław Scherwentke, hence the community wiki)

Let's take an example:

```
% paper.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{A}
\input{B}
\end{document}
```

and `A.tex`:

```
% A.tex
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{4cm}{3cm}
\caption{Dummy Figure}\label{fig:dummy_figure}
\end{figure}
```

and then, `B.tex`:

```
% B.tex
Figure \ref{fig:dummy_figure} is a dummy figure.
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: sorry I have a question, what if A and B are not in the same folder ?

Comment: @Nizar `\input{/path/to/A}` and then `\input{/path/to/B}`.