# cross-references across different subfiles

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles

I have a problem with a cross-reference across two files. My files are arranged like in this example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148818/147782

two files included in the main file with `\input` and I'm trying to reference from one to the other. I tried creating some short example files and these work. So I'm assuming the mistake lies with the label.

Is it possible, that `\label` has to be tied to an object?, as in, can it be on its own or does it need an anchor? Because my appendix is a bit weirdly built as I have to include `.pdf` files there, so there is no actual object like a title or an image there, just links to files. The really weird thing is, I just found out, that some of the labels work, whereas others don't. E.g. from the ones here, CFA1 and CFBS1 work, whereas NMBS does not, even though they are positioned in the same place and all... I'm using `\pageref{NMBS}` to reference them.

```
\section*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\pagebreak
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Coal Face Shot by Shot Analysis Part I} \label{CFA1}
\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Appendices/CF1Protokoll}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Coal Face Bar Sheet Part I} \label{CFBS1}
\includepdf[pages=-,  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Appendices/CF1Rhythm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Night Mail Bar Sheet} \label{NMBS}
\includepdf[pages=-,  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Appendices/NM5Rhythm}
```

zipped short version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dbr527094q3pg7/Appendix.zip?dl=0

Comment: What do you suspect `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Coal Face Shot by Shot Analysis Part I} \label{CFA1}` to do? You're labelling basically nothing then

Comment: Do you have the sources of your `CF1Rhytm` etc. files as well? You can directly input them (stripping the `documentclass` around them), otherwise use `\usepackage{xr}` and its `\externaldocument` file, this needs the `.aux` files of the 'subfiles', however

Comment: well it creates an entry in the ToC without printing an actual title which it does, this works for all of them and shows the correct page number. As said, I can't set a real title because then it would use a whole page just for the title as the pdf needs a complete page.

Comment: I know what `\addcontentsline` does, but the `\label` is pretty useless there

Comment: yes I do have the sources, I wrote them myself. I don't think I can strip the stuff around it. I tried it with input in the beginning. The problem is, that I need LaTeX to type the page number on top of the inserted pdf page and this somehow did not work using \input or at least I was too stupid to get it to work. Also: why would it work with one label but not with the other? I can't see any difference between them.

Comment: I basically need to be able to reference to the place where the pdf starts to reference to this particular part of my appendix with a page number.

Comment: You're most likely referencing something different than what you expect. What is `\pgref` supposed to be. I don't know a macro named `\pgfref`, but `\pageref`

Comment: possible.. can I put an anchor there and label that? I basically need something that is on that page but stays invisible.

Comment: my bad, I meant \pageref. it's correct in the document though

Comment: `\usepackage{crossreftools}` right at the end of the preamble, i.e. just before `\begin{document}` and `\crtcrossreflabel*{Some text relating to NMBS}{NMBS}`, for example instead of `\label{NMBS}`. This will place a proper label anchor. If you need hyperlinks, place a `\phantomsection` before `\crtcrossreflabel*`

Comment: By the way, `includepdf` allows specification of ToC entries in its key-value interface, i.e. see the `addtotoc` key

Comment: that would actually be perfect since it includes toc-entry as well as label, but I can't get it to work either. I entered it like this and it doesn't even create the toc entry nor does the label work:
    \includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,subsection,2,Coal Face Shot by Shot Analysis Part I,CFA1} landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Appendices/CF1Protokoll}

Comment: As long there is no full, compilable document, I can't provide much help here

Comment: I added a zipped shortened version to the main post. Also I found an answer to one of my questions. It seems to work if the label is placed inside an environment. (for the not so elegant solution, making it even less so, but at least it works then ;))

Answer (score 1):

The O.P. missed a comma after `pagecommand{}addtotoc`, i.e. it should be `pagecommand{...},addtotoc=....`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,british]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages} % pdf package http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\input{B}
\input{A}

\end{document}
```

In A.tex:

```
\section*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\pagebreak
%\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Coal Face Bar Sheet Part I} \label{CFBS1}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, addtotoc={1,subsection,2,Coal Face Bar Sheet Part I,CFBS1}]{CFBS1} 
%\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Coal Face Shot by Shot Analysis Part II} \label{CFA2}
\includepdf[pages=-,  landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},addtotoc={1,subsection,2,Coal Face Shot by Shot Analysis Part I,CFA2}]{CFA2}
```

[image]