# reference to tex document

Tags: cross-referencing

is there any way where i can put a label on a full latex document and refer to it in another tex file.

e.g. `supplement.tex`

```
\documentclass[review,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\label{supplement1}


something

\end{document}
```

and in the main document `main.tex` do something like:

```
    \documentclass[review,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
\externaldocument{supplement}
    \begin{document}


    something is refered from Supplement file~\ref{supplement1}

    \end{document}
```

***EDIT***

thanks for your comments, what i basically want is not to refer to a section or chapter in another document, but i want to refer to the whole document.

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14365/21344), I believe it does what you want. If not, please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: the latex cross reference mechanism to sections (including the `xr` system for external references) are designed to produce dynamically constructed numbers. For the file reference, if you just want the filename, just type the filename (or if you want it to be a link, hyperref can make it so)

Comment: The "duplicate" question is answered by `xr` which does not answer this question. I voted for reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Your question could be clearer (as seen from the comments and close/open votes) but I think you want

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \begin{document}


    something is refered from Supplement file~\href{supplement1.pdf}{supplement1}

\end{document}
```

which makes the word `supplement1` a link to `supplement1.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

You can use the `xr` package to reference to other LaTeX document.

In the file `supplementmain.tex` you say:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{supplement}
...
\ref{ext:supplement}
```

**Note:** normally `xr` doesn't add hyperlinks. Use `zref` package for this. You only need to replace `\externaldocument` with `\zexternaldocument`.

## Solution 2

A minimal working example taken from the following site: [GUIT](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/90877-riferimenti-a-label-qesterneq?lang=it#91033)

**First.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[S-]{Second}[Second.pdf]
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}\label{chp:one}
\chapter{Two}\label{chp:two}
Bla Bla Bla.
\end{document}
```

**Second.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[F-]{First}[First.pdf]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Beginning}\label{chp:One}
Hello!
\chapter{Continuation}
I read chapters~\ref{F-chp:one}~and~\ref{F-chp:two} of the first file.

\end{document}
```

[GUIT](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/90877-riferimenti-a-label-qesterneq?lang=it#91033) also says that in this way you have the hyperlink to the first file.

Comment: Hi, this did not work, im still getting `??` in the place of `\ref{ext:supplement}` when i run pdflatex

Comment: It could be because both files must to be in the same folder.

Comment: they are in the same folder already

Comment: @ifreak the above assumes that there is a label `\label{ext:supplement}` in the external document, and that you want the number associated with that label.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Taanks I forgot to explain this thing

Comment: @marchetto the ?? is gone, but i don't get anynumber.

Comment: You may declare any number of such external documents. I' looking for a solution with an other package...

Comment: I've edit my answer with a new second solution. On my station both solutions works.