# How to refer to labels in other documents?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have two documents `file1.tex` and `file2.tex` in two different folds `fold1` and `fold2`, which are in the fold `father`.

In file1, I defined `\label{file1:hello}`, how do I use it in file2?

Comment: I think the `xr` package would help.

Comment: If you wish to cross-reference with the aid of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), then see [Does `hyperref` work between two files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41539/5764)

Comment: @Werner how to set the relative path correct?

Comment: @MaMing: You should read the linked post. It requires you to define (say) `\externaldocument{../fold2/file2}` in `file1.tex`. Then you would use the label as-is: `\label{hello}`. Otherwise, if you may have duplicate labels (`hello` in `file1.tex` and `hello` in `file2.tex`), then you should use `\externaldocument[<prefix>]{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

I replace here the same answer given for **[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160088/reference-to-tex-document/160092?noredirect=1#comment365791_160092)**: in this case solutions are for files in the same folder.

## Solution 1

You can use the `xr` package to reference to other LaTeX document.

In the file `supplementmain.tex` you say:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{supplement}
...
\ref{ext:supplement}
```

**Note:** normally `xr` doesn't add hyperlinks. Use `zref` package for this. You only need to replace `\externaldocument` with `\zexternaldocument`.

## Solution 2

A minimal working example taken from the following site: [GUIT](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/90877-riferimenti-a-label-qesterneq?lang=it#91033)

**First.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[S-]{Second}[Second.pdf]
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}\label{chp:one}
\chapter{Two}\label{chp:two}
Bla Bla Bla.
\end{document}
```

**Second.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[F-]{First}[First.pdf]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Beginning}\label{chp:One}
Hello!
\chapter{Continuation}
I read chapters~\ref{F-chp:one}~and~\ref{F-chp:two} of the first file.

\end{document}
```

[GUIT](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/90877-riferimenti-a-label-qesterneq?lang=it#91033) also says that in this way you have the hyperlink to the first file.

If files are in different folders, you can add paths into `\externaldocument`