# Cross-reference in muliple chapter in multi-file thesis

Tags: cross-referencing, multiple-files

I want to cross-reference between different chapters. For example I have `chap2.tex` and `chap3.tex` as files containing all the theorems and methods, respectively. The following chapters 4,5...7 will extensively rely on cross-referencing from these two chapter.

I am using the thesis template from [here](http://phd.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/phd/files/shared/0%20Pages%20EDOC/Modeles_these/latex_template5_57.zip) and I have tried following the solution provided for a [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) using the `xr` package, but it is not working.

Can somebody point out the error I am making? Is there something with the template?

Comment: If you're including these in the same "master document", there's no need for specifically using [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr). A simple `\label` and corresponding `\ref` would suffice.

Comment: @Werner I am keeping each chapter separate as they are around 10 chapters. `\label` and `\ref` works perfectly fine within a chapter on a single `chap.tex` file.

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping each chapter separate"? Do you compile them on their own? If you `\include` each `chapX.tex` as part of a master document, then you can still use `\label`-`\ref`, even though the `\label` is in one file and `\ref` is in another.

Comment: @Werner I `\include` them into the master document as `\include{chap1.tex}`, `\include{chap2.tex}`......Trying to use `\ref` is not giving me any option to include in another chapter as it gives in the same chapter.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps not from your editor's point of view, but it should work for LaTeX. Try it.

Comment: I am using Texmaker, are you able to cross reference between different chapter in different files? what editor do you use? Is this editor specific issue?

Comment: Yes you are. The suggested labels in your `\ref` might not show up, but you can certainly use them.

Comment: The editor doesn't matter. Just type the label and ignore the editor which may claim the cross-reference is undefined. Kile does this for some cross-references which are perfectly well defined. Just ignore your editor - LaTeX will work it out.

Comment: @cfr @Werner, I manged to solve it. I used `\input{chap2}` in the begining of later chapters which provides me the option for label selection. And even after I remove the `\input{chap2}`, they can retain their values.