# How to split a tex file while still keeping correct equation references?

Tags: cross-referencing

I need to split a manuscript into main text and online supplement, as required for publication on a journal. The problem is that in the online supplement, I refer to many equations and theorems in the main text. I don't want to manually change all the references to numbers (e.g. from \ref{eq:1} to (1)). There are too many of them. Is there a good way to do this?

If the journal only requires the pdf files, then I can certainly split the output pdf file. However, the journal asks for both pdf and tex files.

Comment: You're probably interested in [Cross-referencing between different files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5764).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think I may try the xr package.

Comment: Yes, xr package works.