# cross-references from other documents

Tags: cross-referencing, input, standalone

I'm writing on a large document with many tables. Rules require me to provide every table as a standalone PDF file as well, so I do this:

In `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}\label{sec:hello}
\input{table}
\end{document}
```

In `table.tex`

```
\documentclass[float=true,preview=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
   A table in section \ref{sec:hello}
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Now, at first glance, this works nicely. However, in the standalone version of the table, the section reference is broken for obvious reasons, since LaTeX doesn't know about the section in the standalone file.

I suppose there is some hack to make this work by making LaTeX use the `main.aux` when compiling `table.tex`, but I can't really think of a nice way to handle this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) as suggested here: [Cross-referencing between different files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5764)

Comment: Do you need captions in those standalone table files? If you remove the `table` environment` from `table.tex` and use `\includestandalone` then things will work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I need the captions, I need to check, but `xr` seems to work as intended, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I just discovered one more thing: It would be nice if the tables also had the correct numbers in the standalone. Would this be possible?

Comment: @carsten: What does "correct numbers" mean?

Comment: @Werner: Let's say I have two tables. When compiling `main.tex`, LaTeX assigns them the numbers 1 and 2. Now, compiling the standalone versions, they both get called "Table 1", since they are each the first table in the standalone document. I would like the captions in the standalone to state the table numbers as given in the main document.

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks of creating separate `standalone` documents for content. You may consider using only whatever you have within the `document` environment instead. If there's no reason for using file in the `standalone` format, then I'd suggest doing that.