# clipboard package and references

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, clipboard

I have a main tex file with citation and references.

main.tex:

```
... Lorem ipsum \cite{amet} commodo at, \ref{porttitor} nec risus. ....
```

which in the pdf looks like this:

> ... Lorem ipsum [40] commodo at, (5) nec risus. ....

I would like to copy some of paragraphs from the main.tex to the new.tex.
I know that there is a package for this: clipboard. But it does not work really well with citations and references. Namely I want to preserve the numeration for citation and references.

So, in the new.pdf this should look exactly the same:

> ... Lorem ipsum [40] commodo at, (5) nec risus. ....

Do you know any tricks for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: The [xr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) package might be relevant. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-referencing between different files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files)