# hyperreferencing include files

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, wiki

I have a latex file that i wish to convert into an html document. It is made up of many sub-files with a master document. I want to hyperlink different parts/sections of these files(included/master-file) among themselves just like a wiki.

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/121799 ? (BTW, are you left-handed or right-handed? ;-)

Comment: I wish to create a wiki like <http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quacon.html#quacon>

Answer (score 3):

You can put chapters or sections to standalone pages using a command line option. The hyperlinks can be added using the `\nameref` command provided by the `Hyperref` package. It is based on the standard label/ref mechanism.

You didn't provide any example, so here is my MWE, `sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Site title}
\author{Neutrino}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{hello-world}
\input{another-section}

\end{document}
```

It includes two files, `hello-world.tex`:

```
\chapter{Hello world}
\label{chap:hello-world}
\lipsum
```

The second file is named `another-section.tex`:

```
\chapter{Another section}
\label{chap:another-section}

We can try to link to chapter~\nameref{chap:hello-world}.

\lipsum
```

You can see the `\nameref` command use here.

Compile the document using the following command:

```
make4ht sample.tex "2,sec-filename"
```

The options after the filename require cutting of chapters to standalone HTML files. The names of the generated files will be based on the chapter titles. This feature is enabled using the `sec-filename` option.

The `sample.html` will contain title and table of contents:

[image]

The file `Anothersection.html` contains link to the `Hello world` chapter:

[image]

Comment: make4ht command does not work on my system as it is broken in my texlive 2018<https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/issues/12>. Is there an alternative with htlatex.

Comment: I have accomplished my task by compiling each tex files to be included in final wiki separately/batch command(htlatex?) and linking each of them by using \href{url}.

Comment: @neutrino make4ht should be fixed in TL 2018, it just needs to be updated using `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: My texlive version is already 2018, in which make4ht does not work.

Comment: @neutrino the htlatex call would be `htlatex sample.tex "xhtml,2,sec-filename"`