# How do I reference equation in between two subfiles?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a book, I have a `main.tex`, `Chapter1.tex` and `Chapter2.tex` file.
I have an equation in `Chapter1.tex` and I want to refereed it in `Chapter2.tex`.

I have defined the two chapter in `main.tex` as follows:

```
\include{Chapter1} 
\include{Chapter2}
```

We assume that the equation is labeled in `Chapter 1` under the name \label{eq1}. I have tried to apply [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14365/225622). I added `\usepackage{xr}` in `main.tex`. Then I added `\externaldocument{Chapter1}` in `Chapter2.tex`. However, the result is always (??)

`Chapter1.tex` and `Chapter2.tex` as follows:

Comment: just use `\label` and `\ref` it is all the same document.

Comment: I deleted the subfiles tag as that is for the subfiles package with a non standard way of including files, but you are using `\include` which requires no extra code at all.

Comment: See also `\includeonly`.  You can still access chapter1.aux without actually printing chapter1.