# refs/cite a label in another volume

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I have two documents (say Vol1 and Vol2) in one folder.
Vol2 often refers to statements in Vol 1.

I would like to create a command say `\firstvol`, so to that `\firstvol{thm.pyth}` would produce a citation to the `\label{thm.pyth}` in Vol1; so in pdf it would look like [12.39a Vol1].

Comment: have you checked this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364

Comment: @putianyi888 thank you --- it works.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes (I already answered)